# Unable to replicate constrains programmatically

Tags: ios, swift

I want to add these constrains programmatically in my code:

[image]

So far I got this:

```
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sceneView)
    sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasUnderReference.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playersScoreReference.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    sceneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
    print(sceneView.frame)
```

This prints out:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Why does it prints out those values? Are the constrains not added?

I tried it in viewDidLoad and this func:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    sceneView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
    self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
    sceneScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!
    sceneScene.backgroundColor = .white
    sceneScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
    sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
    let canvasUnderReference = CanvasUnder.layoutMarginsGuide
    let playersScoreReference = playersScore.layoutMarginsGuide
    sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasUnderReference.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playersScoreReference.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
    sceneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: view.frame.width).isActive = true
    print(sceneView.frame)
    sceneView.presentScene(sceneScene)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: CanvasCards)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sceneView)

}
```

Edit 2:

```
override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        sceneView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        sceneView.ignoresSiblingOrder = true
        self.view.addSubview(sceneView)
        sceneScene = SKScene(fileNamed: "MyScene")!
        sceneScene.backgroundColor = .white
        sceneScene.scaleMode = .resizeFill
        sceneView.showsNodeCount = true
        let canvasUnderReference = CanvasUnder.layoutMarginsGuide
        let playersScoreReference = playersScore.layoutMarginsGuide
        sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasUnderReference.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playersScoreReference.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        sceneView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true
        sceneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
        sceneView.presentScene(sceneScene)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: CanvasCards)
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: sceneView)
}
```

It still prints 0, 0, 0, 0

Comment: Where did you add those constraints? As in, which method and at what point in the view life cycle?

Comment: Try using *viewWillLayoutSubviews* or *viewDidLayoutSUbview*, not *viewDidLoad*.

Comment: I had it in viewDidLoad, viewWillLayoutSubvies and viewDidLayoutSubviews, all did not work and all did print 0,0,0,0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Setup the constraints once (for example in `viewDidLoad()`). The constrains will not effect the frames until after `updateConstraints()` has been called (***DO NOT CALL `updateConstraints()`, the system does this***).

In addition, the width constraint should not be set to a constant. You want to constrain it to `self.view`.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    sceneView.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: canvasUnderReference.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: playersScoreReference.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
    sceneView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor).isActive = true

    // This is the proper way to create width constraint.
    sceneView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.widthAnchor).isActive = true
}

override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    print(sceneView.frame)
}
```

I used `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` for the print because I know that will happen after `updateConstraints()` has been called on all the views.

Comment: The problem remains, it still saying 0, 0, 0, 0. See Edit 2 for full code.

Comment: @J.Doe The next place I would look is ensure all other constraints on `sceneView` have been removed or deactivated and `sceneView.translates​Autoresizing​Mask​Into​Constraints` is false. Check that `canvasUnderReference` and `playersScoreReference` are correct.

Comment: translate auto resizing turning off and now it works! Thanks